# Is there a way to mark object in Scala as not holding mutable state?

Tags: scala, immutability

I am relatively new to Scala. I have several helper methods and need to place them somewhere. My instinct is to group helper methods in stateless `object`.

It is concerning however that me or someone else could start adding state to that object with `var` fields. That will cause side-effects that not only helper methods' arguments but state of the object can influence behavior of methods.

I want to have protection from that for now and need to mark object as not holding (mutable) state so that compiler or some validation tool (e.g. Fortify) would raise an error when someone tries to add state to the object. Is it possible in Scala? Is there some `@Immutable` or `@Stateless` annotation?

Example code:

```
object StreamHelpers /* <-- this needs to be marked immutable or stateless */ {

  var something: String = "change me" // <-- this should cause build to fail

  def streamToString(stream: InputStream): String = {
    managed(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      .map(reader => CharStreams.toString(reader)).getTry.get
  }

  // other stuff
}
```

Update: as per discussion in comments, I am interested to know whether in Scala it is possible to:

1. disallow adding `var`-s to an `object`

OR

2. disallow adding both `val`-s and `var`-s to an `object`

with keyword or annotation of any sort. Or is it possible to achieve that with macros or meta-programming if Scala does not support it out of the box?

Comment: Maybe a "val"? I'm Agree with @Pavel

Comment: You're right. A useless comment :/ sorry :/

Comment: Maybe there are some static analysis tools that do this, but that is off topic for StackOverflow. Generally, the way of avoiding such mistakes is usually through a code review process. I don't see how you can fully safe guard any code from future developers.

Comment: To me it is not a conceptual point of protecting code from developers. Rather I am asking whether Scala language with its sophisticated type system has support for such thing as annotating objects as immutable. I consider it as a feature that would make class/object design more apparent.

Comment: Would be easier to simply mark `var` as bad in your code validation tool. With a specific annotation for when it's required.

Comment: You're conflating two different things which I believe is the reason for the `val` vs `var` comments above. "Immutability" means that the state of an object cannot change *after it gets created*. What you're talking about is "raise an error when someone tries to *add* state" during implementation - which is a totally different thing. I'm not surprised people got confused with your question.

Comment: @YoungSpice Thanks, that makes sense. I need a way to describe stateless set of methods. In practice I expect it be more sophisticated: 1) one needs a common constant - `val Something = 123` will be valid in such object; 2) as long as `val` is allowed, anyone could add a field of mutable type. Later makes object mutable in general case because its behavior depends on mutable state. Even when `var`-s and `val`-s are disallowed object's methods could still access global state somewhere else.

Comment: Given that proof of immutability is a hard problem, I guess I am looking for a way to prohibit `var`-s in an `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WartRemover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover). There is no built-in check for that (except one which bans *all* use of `var`), but it shouldn't be hard to write one (and include mutable collection `val`s while you are at it). Alternately, if you only want to mark specific objects as immutable, a [macro annotation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) would take basically the same code.

Comment: I ended up prohibiting `var`-s in [ScalaStyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/) checker since one was already set up for a project.